# Reference request: groups theory and trees

Tags: reference-request

I need to find references to the following two facts (if a second one has a short proof then I can use it instead)

1) Each automorphism of oriented tree has a fixed point or invariant line.

2) Let group $G$ be a free product of finitely many finite groups $G_i$: $G=G_1\ast \cdots\ast G_n.$

If elements $g_1=a$ and $g_2=a^b = b^{-1}ab$ have an infinite order in $G$ and $[g_1,g_2]\ne 1$ in $G$, then $\left \langle g_1^2,g_2^2 \right \rangle\simeq F_2$, where $F_2$ is a free group of rank two.

Comment: Obviously you are considering finite trees for 1).

Answer (score 2):

1.) Each automorphism of a tree fixes a vertex or an edge.

Proof: Let $T$ be a tree. If $|V (T )| = 1$ then clearly the
identity automorphism must fix the vertex. If $|V (G)| = 2$, there are two
automorphisms - the identity and the map that switches the two vertices.
In the latter case, the edge is fixed. Now suppose for all $T$ with $|V (T )| ≤ n$,
every automorphism fixes either an edge or a vertex. Let $|V (T )| = n + 1$
and let $\{v_1, \ldots , v_k\} ∈ V (T )$ be the set of vertices with degree one. We
note that this set is nonempty as $T$ is a tree. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism
of $T$ . Then, $\phi(v_i) ∈ \{v_1, \ldots , v_k\}$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ k$ as automorphisms preserve degrees. Consider $T′ = T \setminus \{v_1, \ldots , v_k\}$. Then $\phi$ is also an automorphism
of $T′$, and $T′$ is also a tree, and $|V (T')| < n+1$. By the induction hypothesis,
$\phi$ fixes an edge or a vertex of $T′$. Thus, $\phi$ fixes an edge or a vertex of $T$.

Comment: Thank you! However, I have knowledge of how it can be proved, but I do not want to include a proof of this fact in my article.

Comment: This is mentioned as a fact in several articles, books and surveys (just google: for example [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwiSmfqnle3LAhWMFJoKHeFsC_gQFghHMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.columbia.edu%2F~cs6204%2Ffiles%2FLec5-Automorphisms.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFCuzUUV46Zqn_VRvE6xi8JgC37vw&sig2=5obSIreYHIVI-v9iDANoWw&bvm=bv.118443451,d.bGQ)). In Diestel's book on graph theory it is an exercise on page $31$.